# Check client connection to SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server

I am having a problem with client application (running on a PC on LAN) connecting to the SQL Server 2008 Express.  The application gets error something like "Server does not exist" 
When running the application right on the VM box where SQL server is installed, no problem.
Executing the PortQry.exe utility on the server shows that SQL Server is listening on port 1433.
The Remote Connection option is checked in the SSMS.
So it could be a firewall issue.  But the question is the following:

Is there a command (like PING) I can execute on the client PC on the LAN that will show if the SQL Server is being accessed?  Just so that I can see that "something" is blocking or not the connection. This would be another way of checking it, besides using the application.

Comment: The **Express** editions do not allow remote connections by default. It can be configured - but you have to explicitly do it yourself. See the duplicate I flagged for an answer on how to do it, step by step

Comment: @marc_s  How do I see the duplicate you flagged?  Where does it show?  Thank you for your suggestion.